# Audio analysis and frequency peak

Tags: audio, frequency, sox, spectrogram, frequency-analysis

I'm getting aan audio signal from a WAV file, and would like to get the peak frequency.

With **SoX** spectrogram, I can "see" this frequency (here 12kHz):

[image]

My need is to find this value, numerically, because it can be fluctuant according to source.

Regards,

Comment: You want to do this with sox or do you want to write some code ?

Comment: I can use both, I personally am more comfortable with command lines.

Comment: OK, well there are a lot of posts here on StackOverflow already about how to do this with code - try searching the tag [fft].

Comment: Thanks @PaulR, I didn't know the Fourier Transformation, I'm going to stody this solution.